# replace URL with href in ajax

Tags: html, ajax

Using following code to display text from another page

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'topic/ginger.php',
        success: function (data) {
            data = $(data).find('div#display');
            $('.res h2').html(data);
                        }
    });

               <a href="topic/ginger.php">
                    <div class="res" id="content" style="background-color:rgb(50, 190, 166)">
                        <h2></h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
```

now i have two div with different `href`

```
               <a href="topic/icecre.php">
                    <div class="res"  id="content" style="background-color:rgb(224, 79, 95)">
                        <h2></h2>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a href="topic/jelly.php">
                    <div class="res" id="content" style="background-color:rgb(92, 184, 92)">
                        <h2></h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
```

As you see `<a href="topic/ginger.php">` is url in ajax code, now i have two other div with different href so different `url` how do i sole this

Comment: Can you show more of your code, this isn't really enough to understand what you are wanting.

Comment: I don't get your question. URL is different? In which divs?

Comment: made some edit to question

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.res').each(function(){
    getAjax($(this).find("h2"), $(this).parent().attr('href'));
});

function getAjax(child, link)
{
   $.ajax({
        url: link,
        success: function (data) {
        data = $(data).find('div#display');
        child.html(data);
    }
    });
}
```

Assuming all your divs are in the res class I would think this would do it, loops throught the res class and grabs the h2 inside it and the href of its parent and passes it to your ajax call to do the work. Havent tested it though.

EDITL just saw your newest edit, you cant have multiple items with the ID = "content" so get rid of them and give them each class ="res"

Comment: this doesn't display text from external page

Comment: without entering `topic/ginger.php` to `URL` in `ajax` how can i get `href` value to place to `URL` automatically

Comment: Im not sure what you mean in the example I provided the href is coming in as the "link" variable for each div, so when put in the url area it is acting as "topic/ginger.php".
Assuming your ajax request and PHP is set correctly it should be putting that data inside the h2. See this little fiddle I made, I skipped over the ajax call because I dont have your PHP code but you can see each div's h2 is being replaced with the link, you need to just fill in the ajax in the middle. http://jsfiddle.net/u7m6jk4b/2/